# Refresh Navigation Menu without closing modal dialog Oracle Apex 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I need to refresh the side navigation menu on pressing a button while working on the modal dialog page. I can't use `window.location.reload(true);` because I still want to be in modal page after the refresh. I tried  `parent.$('.t-Body-nav').trigger('apexrefresh');` but this is not working.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Not all regions are refreshable. Are you sure that one is? If not, you may need to write some JS code that fetches new values and uses them to update the DOM.

Comment: Yea navigation menu refreshes on page load. If I use ```window.location.reload(true);``` it is updated but the whole page reloads and the modal window closes

Comment: The menu probably doesn't refresh on page load, it's just rendered. There are some regions, such as Charts and potentially Interactive Grids, that get their data via Ajax after the initial page load, but most regions don't do this. See if you can refresh the region from the console on the main page (not the modal). If you can't do it from there, you will not be able to do it from the modal either.